# Issues displaying nested api data in React Application

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am doing a react application and I want to fetch data from an api using the useEffect hook. I am receiving the data, but I am having trouble when trying to display 1 of the items in the received object. I have no problem displaying the other items from the data that I want.

When I look at the returned data in the console I see that the property I am trying to display (and gives me error) is actually object nested inside an array.

The error that I get is **"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"**

I think that the problem is that not all data is loaded in the time when it renders, but not sure how to handle this. The problem is the "coinData.description[0]". Is my approach correct

Here is my component:
[Componet First Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj2l3.png)
[Compoent Second Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCVRr.png)

The problem is on row 36 in the second picture

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The **setCoinData** will set the whole answer of your request.

The problem is that **property does not exist** or that you are **trying to render before your fetch was finished**.

For the first case you can **check the answer with a console.log()**.

In the second case you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid this error.